# TFS Relase Management output

Tags: tfs, build, release-management

I have a TFS 2015 Build and Release task and as part of this task I would like to take the output from the build and put it on to a server share under the version number of the software.

E.G.

\Server\App\Build\Versions{VersionNo}\

Answer (score 1):

The "Copy and Publish Build Artefacts" tasks does something that is very close to this by setting the drop type to share. The structure isn't exactly what you're after though.

Instead you can also use a standard File Copy task or even a custom powershell script. The name of the build definition and the build version number are available as variables, so it's not hard to create the folder structure you're after.

Comment: He could set up the structure he wants in his Publish Build Artifacts task though: For the Path configuration, set it up like: \\$(YourServerAsAVariable)\app\$(Build.DefinitionName)\Versions$(Build.BuildNumber) list of variables available by default: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-tasks#predefvariables